# Hostname (FQDN)

Tags: fqdn

Hello i have a short question. I try to install ipsconfig but it ask for the follow thing.

```
Full qualified hostname (FQDN) of the server, eg server1.domain.tld  [server1.example.com]:
```

I don't know what i must fill in here. My domain called devhouse.nl. but i have any kind of name servers. Must i full in my ip adrres or something else?

Edit: or is het my vps hostname?? vps{number}.domain.ext

Tom

Comment: Is devhouse.nl an internal _and_ external domain? Or is it a domain you created for, say, your own systems inside your office?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you DON'T have any kind name servers?
If this is the case, you can put:

server1.devhouse.nl

However, you will have to make sure to specify the IP address that this name resolves to in your local host file (/etc/hosts).

An IP address should also work fine. If ISPConfig is on the same machine as the web server, localhost or 127.0.0.1 will also work.

Answer (score 0):

it is asking for your servername. when your domain is devhouse.nl, it could be www.devhouse.nl. it is not asking for your nameserver (dns-server) names.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in general the fully qualified server name in this case will be in this format:

{server name}.{domain}

You said your domain is devhouse.nl so let's say your server is fungo the fully qualified server name is:

fungo.devhouse.nl

This name does need to be served by DNS somewhere to be useful, but you do not need to know where those name servers are or their names.  It just has to be in the system.